# Override Newtonsoft.Json serialization of single

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am taking a hash of serialized objects on the server and the client to compare for changes. On server, I use javascript JSON.stringify. On client, I use JsonSerializer.JsonSerialize. For the hashes to match, the json rendered must be identical on both sides.

One of the fields is a number in javascript and single in .net. In javascript, it serializes as `"duration": 1`. In .net it serializes as `"duration": 1.0`. This of course makes the hashes fail to match.

How to I get .net to serialize without the trailing zero?

Comment: Don't use a floating point type?

Comment: But the duration may be a non-integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `JsonConverter` to control the format of the float.  You'll need to test it to make sure the format matches over the range of values you are expecting, but this should be pretty close.

```
class FormattedFloatConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(float));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(((float)value).ToString("0.########"));
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` has an overload that accepts a `JsonConverter`, making it pretty straightforward to use:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, new FormattedFloatConverter());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3t6RiR